# finite length and finitely generated

Tags: modules

it seems that a module over a noetherian ring R is  finitely generated if and only if it has finite length (sorry, it turns out to be **false**! i must have had a misunderstanding!)

but why in the following two cases, we have some extra assumptions?

**Example (i)** A module M over a (commutative) noetherian ring R has finite length if and only if it
is finitely generated and AssM consists of only maximal ideals, where AssM is the set of associated primes for M.

(definition: We say that a prime ideal p is an associated prime for M if there
exists m in M such that p = ann m.)

**Example (ii)** in this thesis:
http://digitalcommons.mcmaster.ca/opendissertations/3531/
Page 12 Lemma 2.15: A finitely generated $A$-module is $\Sigma$-torsion if and only if it has finite length.

As i understand: $A$ is "weyl algebra" which is noetherian. 
so why do we need the extra assumption "$\Sigma$-torsion"?

Comment: It would have been best *not* to accept Dietrich's interesting comment as an answer. As your own comment to it makes evident, it does not answer your question!

Comment: but at least he has shown me that this definition of an associated prime is for the case of commutative rings, something i was not aware of. i don't know if R needs to be commutative, but at least the author of the statement as it is, meant it in the commutative environment. 

Comment: Mariano, you are right. I should have used the "Add comment" field.

Comment: Dear Paslig. If your question is whether for modules $M$ over a left-Artinian ring $R$, finite length and finite generation are equivalent properties, then the answer is yes. This is a basic fact.

Any module of finite length is finitely generated.

As you remark, being left-artinian, $R$ is also left-noetherian, hence has finite length itself. And so are $R^n$, for any integer~$n$, and its quotients. So a finitely generated $R$-module has finite length.

This is explained in (almost) every book on algebra, eg, Lang, Jacobson, or Bourbaki (Algèbre, chapter 8).

Comment: Cher ACL, merci beaucoup pour votre réponse rapide! ce qui me dérange, c'est la phrase dans la thèse "http://digitalcommons.mcmaster.ca/opendissertations/3531/" Page 12 Lemma 2.15: A finitely generated A-module is Σ-torsion if and only if it has finite length, where A is a weyl algebra (which is noetherian). Pourquoi nous avons besoin de la supposition "Σ-torsion" ? 

Comment: Dear Paslig, Unless I am very confused, your first sentence is quite wrong.  E.g. $\mathbb Z$ is Noetherian, and is f.g. (indeed cyclic) as a module over itself, but is not finite length as a module over itself.  The same remark will apply with $\mathbb Z$ replaced by any Noetherian ring that is not Artinian.  That is why all the other hypotheses are necessary.  Regards, 

Comment: Dear Emerton,

Thank you. i reread the comments from others and i realize i have had a misunderstanding. i have edited my question in order not to confuse others!

Kind regards, 

Comment: Cher Paslig. L'algèbre de Weyl n'est pas artinienne, mais page 11 de cette thèse, Zhang démontre que tout quotient non trivial de cette algèbre est de longueur finie (bien sûr, c'est l'algèbre de Weyl en *une* variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (long) comment:
the definition of an associated prime for $M$ you are mentioning is for the case of commutative rings. There are several problems with this definition, if $R$ is noncommutative. This is discussed in the following thesis: http://math.fullerton.edu/sannin/Research/thesis2.pdf.

The author uses the following definition instead (Def. $14$): Let $R$ be a ring, not necessarily commutative. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. An Ideal $P$ is called an associated prime of $M$ if there exists a prime submodule $N\subseteq M$ such that $P = ann(N)$. Here a nonzero $R$-module $N$ is called *prime* if $ann(N) = ann(N′)$ for every nonzero submodule $N′ ⊆ N$.

Edit: As to the implications of finitely generated and finite length for $M$, for $R$ being noncommutative: if $R$ is left-Artinian (hence also left-Noetherian) then these are still equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. :) i appreciate it very much.

what is the relationship between finite length and finitely generated? when does one imply the other and vice versa?

Comment: (@Dietrich, regarding your comment aboveÑ I think your use of an answer to write your comment is quite fine, as it is often a pain to type long comments!)